# to_json :only in multidimensional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In rails with `to_json` and `:only`, I call to specific keys:

```
 @location_for_map.limit(5).all.to_json(:only => [:name, :lat, :lng])
```

But how do I call subkeys in a multidimensional dictionary?

```
{ "_id" : { "e" : "test", "d" : "2011-04-27" }, "value" : { "ppa" : 20, "hf" : 0, "dg5" : 5, "dg10" : 0, "tma" : 12, "tmi" : 7, "smi" : 0, "sma" : 13 } }
```

How can I call only to value.ppa?